# dynamic treemap shiny < filter by input = Year value >

Tags: r, input, dynamic, filter, treemap

I'm trying to generate a dynamic treemap ( which btw works ), but I'm having issues at the time of changing the source set to have it delimited to an specific "YEAR" from where the data belongs to, so:

- I have an input called "d_Year" that is basically a drop down with a Year to Year values extracted from a different list ( 2016, 2017 ... )
- I want the data loaded by the treemap is updated based on the Year value selected on Shiny app ( I have it set up Server.R and UI.R separated files with a .R file that is sourced to load all variables )
- The following code works just fine:

  ```
   
      m_df_map=m_df_clean %>%

      dplyr::group_by(
      IOT = m_df_clean$IOT,
      Country = m_df_clean$Country,
      Category = m_df_clean$Category
      )%>%
      tally() 
      master_tree_data=treemap(m_df_map, index = c("IOT","Country","Category"), 
      vSize = "n")

      output$master_geo_tree=renderD3tree2({d3tree2(master_tree_data)})
  ```
- I have tried to add an Observe event to the input$d_Year object but still not working at all, it doesn't fail, but it doesn't filter either:

  ```
  observe({
  if (input$d_Year == " All") {
  m_df_clean=m_df[m_df$Phase %in% all_accounts,]
  }
  else {
  m_df_clean=m_df[(m_df$Phase %in% all_accounts)&(m_df$Launch %in% 
  Launch_table_PMA$Launch_Name[Launch_table_PMA$year == input$d_Year]),]
  }
  })
  observeEvent(input$d_Year,{
  if (input$d_Year == " All") {
  m_df_clean=m_df[m_df$Phase %in% all_accounts,]
  }
  else {
  m_df_clean=m_df[(m_df$Phase %in% all_accounts)&(m_df$Launch %in%                                 
  Launch_table_PMA$Launch_Name[Launch_table_PMA$year == input$d_Year]),]
  }
  })
  ```

My apologies if asking something simple, but I have tried for so long already, I'm out of ideas, tried adding the if logic to the renderD3tree2 logic, but that was even a bigger failure, so hopefully one of you can bring some light into this issue.

Thanks in advance Team. . .

Comment: Can you share the complete code, to make it easier to reproduce and rewrite the code.

Comment: of course @AlexanderLeow ... made it available in here:  https://github.com/alhidalg/PMA_bug  
 Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will need to install d3treeR later.